# React Developer Tools Shows "Waiting for roots to load..."

Tags: preact

I've just switched to Preact 8.4.2 and would like to get the React Developer Tools to work as well. In my webpack.config.js, I've added:

```
alias: {
            react: 'preact-compat',
            'react-dom': 'preact-compat'
        }
```

In my entry .js file, I've added:
`require('preact/debug');`

After adding these, I was getting an error when attempting to build:

```
Module parse failed: /myProject/node_modules/preact/src/preact.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { h, h as createElement } from './h';
| import { cloneElement } from './clone-element';
| import { Component } from './component';
 @ ./~/preact/debug.js 6:14-31
```

I only had .jsx files loading with babel-loader (not .js), so I added an additional entry in my webpack.config.js file:

```
         {
             test: /\.js$/,
             include: /node_modules\/preact/,
             loader: 'babel-loader'
         },
```

After adding this entry, I'm able to build without issues, but my React Developer Tools just shows:

> Waiting for roots to load...
>   to reload the inspector [click here]

Comment: I believe this happens when the devtools are not the first thing to be loaded. Try moving the devtools import to the top of your root file.

Comment: Thanks @pmkro. I've tried adding that to the top of my entry file, but I'm seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Hmm, in my setup I don't have the alias's set.

Answer (score 0):

Something is either up with your preact app or your webpack config.  I just solved a similar problem.

First step, check if its your preact. If you have no console errors, drop your preact into this working boilerplate (you'll have to do a little rewiring to get it working) https://github.com/developit/preact-boilerplate

If after firing it up with your code, Devtools works as expected, then there is something wrong with your build. In that case it turns into a game of line by line updating your (mostly) working build to match preact-boilerplate.

In my case, I had included "src" in my webpack resolve. This threw no errors in terminal/console, and the build worked perfectly otherwise. Once I found it, devtools started working.